# How do I install LILO boot loader with Ubuntu and Windows dualboot?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows, dual-boot, lilo

I want to use the LILO boot loader so I can use EasyBCD to show a Ubuntu listing on the Windows Boot Manager screen, but I don't know how. Please make this as simple as possible, as I don't know much about Linux or LILO. My computer is only Legacy boot mode, no UEFI

Comment: if you are using the windows boot manager, then you don't need the linux boot loader, as far as i know

Comment: UEFI is current, grub2 or grub is legacy - lilo is prehistoric. Also EasyBCD is for Windows installs. If it's Windows 10, then the Linux OS will need to be EFI compatiable to even  install it on the Windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

The Linux Loader (lilo) can be installed through:

```
sudo apt install lilo
```

The configuration of the `/etc/lilo.conf` file can be found on Debian Wiki [LILO](https://wiki.debian.org/LILO) and the [Ubuntu manpages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/lilo.8.html).